# How to keep empty entity during Geopandas Spatial Join

Tags: python, spatial-join, geopandas

Is that possible to keep entities who haven't join entities in Geopandas Spatial Join ?

In

```
join = gpd.sjoin(buf, grouped_aquis, op='contains')
```

I would like to keep buf's entities that haven't grouped_aquis' entities joined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `sjoin` does a 'inner' join, meaning that only those records are kept that actually joined with a record in `grouped_aquis`. 
To also keep the ones that did not have a joining match, you can use an 'left' join:

```
join = gpd.sjoin(buf, grouped_aquis, op='contains', how='left')
```